# How to change layout of shop page in wordpress?

Tags: plugins, php, woocommerce-offtopic

Currently I am working on shop page. And according to the design I have to insert a banner after 4th product and after 7th product and I have 3 products in each row and Banner's size is equal to the width of 2 products.This is what i required.
[image]

I have tried it via jquery with code shown below.

```
$("#left-area > ul > li:nth-child(4)").after('<img src="http://localhost/jew/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/selection-page-copy_03.jpg">');
```

Image is inserted correctly in correct position but problem is, It is changing the layout of whole area below that banner as shown in image below

[image]

I have tried editing template of woocommerce but I saw there list of products are generated dynamically and I am confused where to put code for image.So I tried Jquery.
So, Please help me how to fit banner so that products position changes according to banner but in the proper way.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use jQuery to place a image into your shop page (since there is proper way to do this). Instead read the template override methods in Woocommerce: https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/

1. Copy woocommerce folder into your theme (if you don't have the folder inside main theme/child theme).
2. Navigate to your_theme/woocommerce/templates/archive-product.php (this is just an example on how to override your shop template files).
3. Write a logic inside the template to insert a section after odd iterations.

Comment: I am using the same overriding  method and I am not a php and wordpress master so it would be great if you provide some lines of code with a few lines of description.